Find my value in a range of key-values in an array of objects
I need to find my value in a range of key-values in an array of objects. And then perform some math on the object that matches the criteria.
const array-of-objects = [
          {w1: 0.1, w2 0.5, Jv1: 6.13, Jv2: 2.75, a: 3.89},
{w1: 0.5, w2 2, Jv1: 2.75, Jv2: 1.36, a: 3.54},
{w1: 2, w2 4, Jv1: 1.36, Jv2: 0.95, a: 3.57},
{w1: 4, w2 9.63, Jv1: 0.95, Jv2: 0.55, a: 3.5},
{w1: 9.63, w2 35, Jv1: 0.55, Jv2: 0.3, a: 3.5},
{w1: 35, w2 78.03, Jv1: 0.3, Jv2: 0, a: 3.5}]

My pseudo code
const look-up-val = 3;
if (array-of-objects.w1=<look-up-val=<array-of-objects.w2)
const m = Math.log(array-of-objects.w2/array-of-objects.w1) / Math.log(array-of-objects .Jv2/array-of-objects.Jv1);
const b = Math.log(array-of-objects.a);
const logJv = m*Math.log(look-up-val)+b;
const Jv = 10^logJv

I tried
const a = [{s: 3, d: 6, q: 33}]
<-undefined
if (a.s<=5>=a.d) {console.log(a.q)}
<-undefined

and get lost.

Can you show an example as what you are trying to achieve?

Well, the 1 Answer below shows exactly of what I want to achieve.

Ahh ok so your problem is solved haha great

@Spidy My question boils down to calculation of log-log link

The function findAndCalculate will iterate over the array, find the object where lookUpVal is between w1 and w2, and then perform the calculations as per your pseudo code. If it finds a matching object, it will return the calculated Jv value; otherwise, it will return null.


const arrayOfObjects = [
  { w1: 0.1, w2: 0.5, Jv1: 6.13, Jv2: 2.75, a: 3.89 },
  { w1: 0.5, w2: 2, Jv1: 2.75, Jv2: 1.36, a: 3.54 },
  { w1: 2, w2: 4, Jv1: 1.36, Jv2: 0.95, a: 3.57 },
  { w1: 4, w2: 9.63, Jv1: 0.95, Jv2: 0.55, a: 3.5 },
  { w1: 9.63, w2: 35, Jv1: 0.55, Jv2: 0.3, a: 3.5 },
  { w1: 35, w2: 78.03, Jv1: 0.3, Jv2: 0, a: 3.5 }
];

const lookUpVal = 3;

// Function to find the object and perform calculations
function findAndCalculate(array, value) {
  for (let obj of array) {
    if (value >= obj.w1 && value <= obj.w2) {
      const m = Math.log(obj.w2 / obj.w1) / Math.log(obj.Jv2 / obj.Jv1);
      const b = Math.log(obj.a);
      const logJv = m * Math.log(value) + b;
      const Jv = Math.pow(10, logJv); // Use Math.pow for exponentiation
      return Jv;
    }
  }
  return null; // Return null if no matching object is found
}

const result = findAndCalculate(arrayOfObjects, lookUpVal);
console.log(result); // This will log the calculated Jv value




Thank you very much, very useful answer!
